# Which set is this roller from?

Tags: set-identification

We found this roller build. Is this from a set? I looked through the instruction manuals on the LEGO app and did a Google image search but no success.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is from [Batman and the Joker (76013)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/76013-1/batman-the-joker-steam-roller/):

[image: Set box photo]